# NHibernate, generics mapping with common interface

Tags: nhibernate

I've run into a nhibernate dilemma that I'm sure can be solved, cause I haven't run into a problem yet that can't be.
I have a couple of small classes:

```
class PropertyDataString : IPropertyData
  string Value {get; set;}
  void Render() { ..render string property.. }

class PropertyDataSelection : IPropertyData
  string Value {get; set;}
  void Render() { ..render selection property.. }
```

and the interface:

```
interface IPropertydata
  string Value { get; set; }
  void Render() {}
```

Now I have a parent class:

```
class Parent
  List<IProperty> Properties
```

The question how can I map this? As you see both PropertyDataString and PropertyDataSelection has the same properties only difference is in the interface implemented methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chapter 8. Inheritance Mapping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance)

In this case, I recommend the [Table per class hierarchy](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperclass) strategy.

Comment: I didn't know that it allowed you to return an interface, but it seems it does. I'll try it.